# Replacing data using java

Tags: java

I would like to replace data in a file with some new data and rename the file with a different name in java. I have the old file saved in the same class directory as the code to carry out the changes is saved. The command that I use in the command prompt is as below.

```
java ReplacingText oldfile newfile oldstring newstring
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ReplacingText (wrong name: replacingtext/ReplacingText)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Could someone shed some light on it.

```
package replacingtext;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReplacingText 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        if (args.length !=4)
        {
            System.out.println(
            "Usage: java ReplaceText sourceFile targetFile oldStr newStr");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
        if(!sourceFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Source file " + args[0]+" does not exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File targetFile = new File(args[1]);
        if (targetFile.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Target File " + args[1] + "already exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(targetFile);

        while (input.hasNext())
        {
            String s1=input.nextLine();
            String s2=s1.replaceAll(args[2],args[3]);
            output2.println(s2);
        }
        input.close();
        output2.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And the error you receive is ...?

Comment: I am using the command java ReplaceText oldfile newfile oldstring newstring

Comment: Bunch of garbage saying that the file does not exits or something

Comment: Do I need to do something else instead of compiling it in the netbeans

Comment: Please add this "*garbage*" to your post.

Comment: It is in command prompt. I do not know how to copy it

Comment: Make sure you're passing it a complete path to your source file, or that your source file exists in the same directory as your _compiled_ code (not the .java file, but the .class file produced by compilation).

Comment: It does exists in the same directory. But does the whole directory have to be in a java folder or something.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you can copy text from the command prompt [like this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/copy-to-the-clipboard-from-the-windows-command-prompt/) - written for Vista, but should work on 7 too. [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/windows_dos_copy.mspx?mfr=true) are the instructions for XP.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ReplacingText (wrong
name: replacingtext/ReplacingText)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)

Comment: There I have added the error message

Comment: You've given your class a package declaration, which means you'll run it a bit differently. Suppose you've just compiled your java file and it's located at `C:\projects\replacingtext\ReplacingText.class`, you _must_ `cd` to `C:\projects` and type the following: `java replacingtext.ReplacingText oldfile newfile oldstring newstring`

Comment: The error is not in your code, nor it means that something wrong with the files you're working with. It's not an exception that your program throws. It's an error produced by `JVM` itself.

**Java cannot find your class file**.

Answer (score 1):

i found it on the net.
first, i make a direcoty,name as "replacingtext" ,the package name.
then, i move the complied class "ReplacingText.class" into it.
last, i run "java replacingtext.ReplacingText "c:/s.txt" "c:/t.txt" haha yes" in "replacingtext" parent directory.

bingo...it works..

but.. i don't konw why..
perhaps the classLoader find the class by the relative path ,not just the class name...

Comment: "*the classLoader find the class by the relative path ,not just the class name...*" As you say: bingo. You've got it. Here's the reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html

Answer (score 0):

first,i tested the method like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String sourceFile = "c://s.txt";
        String targetFile = "c://t.txt";
        String oldS = "haha";
        String newS = "yes";
        test(new String[]{sourceFile,targetFile,oldS,newS});

        //      test(args);
    }

    private static void test(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (args.length != 4) {
            System.out
                    .println("Usage: java ReplaceText sourceFile targetFile oldStr newStr");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File sourceFile = new File(args[0]);
        if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Source file " + args[0] + " does not exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        File targetFile = new File(args[1]);
        if (targetFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Target File " + args[1] + " already exist");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        Scanner input = new Scanner(sourceFile);
        PrintWriter output2 = new PrintWriter(targetFile);

        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String s1 = input.nextLine();
            String s2 = s1.replaceAll(args[2], args[3]);
            output2.println(s2);
        }
        input.close();
        output2.close();
    }
```

it works.

then, i tested based on the method above like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        test(args);
}
```

java ReplacingText c://s.txt c://t.txt haha yes

it worked ,too..

ps:cause i didn't config the JAVA_HOME,so I run it in my jdk/bin directory.

Comment: You removed `package replacingtext;` from the OP's code and that allowed you to run it the way you described.

Comment: i found it.
first, i make a direcoty,name as "replacingtext" ,the package name.
then, i move the complied class "ReplacingText.class" into it.
last, i run "java replacingtext.ReplacingText "c:/s.txt" "c:/t.txt" haha yes" in "replacingtext" parent directory.
bingo...